# How to get Twilio Geo Permissions set in Account via API?

Tags: php, twilio

I'm using Twilio PHP Library to communicate with Twilio API. I need to find out which countries are allowed in client's Twilio account via their API. Did anybody found an API call to find this out?

I looked into [Twilio API Documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api) and [PHP Twilio API reference](https://twilio-php.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/rest.html), but did not found anything helpful.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to do it via the API. You must do this via [the console](https://www.twilio.com/console/sms/settings/geo-permissions) under settings Geo Permissions.

Comment: 6.3 years later, unfortunately this seems to be still unfeasible. I'm using the python rest client and I can't find a way to retrieve the list of geo permissions from the API. It would be really helpful to dynamically enable countries in our app for us, as we use mobile numbers (and 2FA powered by Twilio) as user identifiers. Hopefully someone from Twilio see this.